# Solving definite integrals with periodic integrand

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, periodic-functions

So, the question  is:
If $f(2-x) = f(2+x)$ and $f(4-x) = f(4+x)$ where $f(x)$ is a function for which
$$\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx =5$$ ,

then prove that :
$$\int_{0}^{50}f(x)dx =125$$
$$\int_{-4}^{46}f(x)dx =125$$
$$\int_{2}^{52}f(x)dx =125$$

also comment whether $\int_{1}^{51}f(x)dx =125$ is true or false.

My approach:
since $f(2-x) = f(2+x)$ , replace $x$ by $x+2$
and we get $f(x) = f(4+x)$ hence  period of
$f(x)$ is $4$
now,

$$\int_{0}^{50}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{48}f(x)dx +\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx  $$
hence
$$\int_{0}^{50}f(x)dx =12* \int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx +\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx  $$
which becomes
$$\int_{0}^{50}f(x)dx =12*( \int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{2}f(x+4)dx) +5  $$
so,we get $$\int_{0}^{50}f(x)dx =125$$

similarly for
$$\int_{-4}^{46}f(x)dx $$,substitute $x+4=t$
therefore,
$$\int_{-4}^{46}f(x)dx =\int_{0}^{50}f(t)dt  =125 $$

however I am not able to prove on the final part and comment on  whether $\int_{1}^{51}f(x)dx =125$ is true or false.Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\int_2^{52} f(x)dx=\int_0^{52} f(x)dx -\int_0^{2} f(x)dx=(13)\int_0^{4} f(x)dx-5$.

Comment: yes, got it what about comment part

Comment: There is not enough information to evaluate $\int_1^{51}f(x)dx$. @Gingerbread

Comment: alright it's fine

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, it can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} \int_{1}^{51} f(x) dx &=\int_{1}^{3} f(x) dx+\int_{3}^{51} f(x) dx\\ &=\int_{0}^{2} f(x+1) dx+120\\&\ne 125\tag{$\because\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx=5$}\end{align}$$

Comment: How do you know that $\int_0^{2}f(x+1)dx \neq 5$?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, because the graph will shift on left side by $1$ unit and so the area will change as function has period $4$.